# Phoenix: Ordering a query set

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm [a noob] playing around with the Phoenix framework for fun and building a small twitter clone. I everything working, however, I want to order the tweets by the `updated_at` field (ascending). As you can see from tweet_controller, I have tried messing around with an order_by clause, but this did nothing for me.

**Question**

How do I achieve this? Within the EEx or within the tweet_controller itself?

**tweet/index.html.eex**

```
<div class="row">
  <%= for tweet <- @tweets do %>

  <h4><%= tweet.tweet %></h4>

  <% end %> 
</div>
```

**controllers/tweet_controller.ex**

```
...
alias TodoApp.Tweet

def index(conn, _params) do
  tweets = Repo.all(Tweet, order_by: tweet)
  render(conn, "index.html", tweets: tweets)
end
...
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use an [Ecto Query](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html):

```
query = from(t in Tweet, order_by: t.updated_at)
tweets = Repo.all(query)
```

You may want to consider defining a function in your Tweet model for the query.

```
def ordered(query) do
  from t in query,
    order_by: t.updated_at
end
```

You can also use the function syntax:

```
def ordered(query) do
  query
  |> order_by([t], t.updated_at)
end
```

Then you can use this in your controller:

```
tweets = Tweet |> Tweet.ordered() |> Repo.all()
```

Here is a good post on queries: http://blog.drewolson.org/composable-queries-ecto/

Comment: Just to confirm though, this can't be done with EEx?

Comment: @plotplot This is the sort of thing that belongs in the database (since the database will sort before the query is executed which is important for pagination.)  Even if you did want to sort using `Enum.sort` I would perform that sort of thing in the controller and not the template.