# How to show all records of a model in Phoenix select field

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have following models...

1. `Page`
2. `Category`

i have following code in `new` action of `page_controller.ex`

```
def new(conn, _params) do
  changeset = Page.changeset(%Page{})
  categories = Repo.all(Category)
  render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset, categories: categories)
end
```

I have following code for select field in page/new.html.eex

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= label f, :category_id, "Parent", class: "control-label" %>
  <%= select f, :category_id, @categories ,class: "form-control" %>
</div>
```

It should show all categories in select field so i can choose one category for the page but unfortunately i am unable to find the problem. if you have any suggestion please let me know.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [select/4](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#select/4) function expects a list of tuples for the 3rd argument.

From the docs:

> Values are expected to be an Enumerable containing two-item tuples (like maps and keyword lists) or any Enumerable where the element will be used both as key and value for the generated select.

Try changing your controller to:

```
categories = Repo.all(Category) |> Enum.map(&{&1.name, &1.id})
```

This can also be done at the query level:

```
query = from(c in Category, select: {c.name, c.id})
categories = Repo.all(query)
```

See [Phoenix: Ordering a query set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33803754/phoenix-ordering-a-query-set) for an explanation of defining a query as a function in your model.

Comment: You are always very helpful... Thank you so much. You know, i started a production app just because i know i will get prompt help from elixir community and specially from you.

Comment: By the way, how do i print `page.category.name` in template

Comment: This `&({ &1.name, &1.id}` renders correct format for me.

Comment: @Murtza If you have a `belongs_to` association then you can do `<%= page.category.name %>`  Make sure you do `category = Repo.get(Page, id) |> Repo.preload(:category)` to ensure the association is loaded.